# Returning a zero as value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following values within a SQL function that I am tyring to get the calcuation to work.  The values are as follows:

value1: 1.567276144

value2: 278576312934.824

The equation is `value1 / value2`

Excel returns the following value: 0.000000000005626020847823060000 (which is correct)

However in SQL-Server it returns:  0.000000000000000

The datatype is a `decimal(38,24)`

Why does the 12th-15th decimal place not appear?  I know the values is very small but we need percision for our accrediation as we do scientific work.

Comment: The result datatype is `decimal(38,6)`. Theoretically it would be `decimal(101,63)` under [the rules for division] `p = 38 - 24 + 24 + max(6, 24 + 38 + 1)` and `s=max(6, 24 + 38 + 1)` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) but this isn't possible so [it gets truncated to that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith do you have a possible solution for how I can obtain this value without using a float?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says the correct result is [0.000000000005626020846814357596555499572259401825458070347050846325](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.567276144%2F278576312934.824). If you use different datatypes you can get greater accuracy (than Excel) with `SELECT CAST(1.567276144 AS DECIMAL(10,9))/ CAST(278576312934.824 AS DECIMAL(15,3))` which returns `0.0000000000056260208468143`. Might not be very practical though. Maybe something in the CLR that you can use with CLR integration?

Answer (score 0):

Decimal precision is 17 as long as I remember, use float instead

EDIT: sorry, thought of column definition

Answer (score 0):

Follows a way but using float is not a good idea as float is an approximate datatype:

```
declare  @val1 decimal(38,24) = 1.567276144 
declare  @val2 decimal(38,24) = 278576312934.824
declare  @val3 decimal(38,24)
select @val3 = cast (cast(@val1 as float)/cast (@val2 as float) as decimal(38,24));
select @val3;
```